# javascript date issue - 0 into 1?

Tags: javascript, calendar

I've created a little script for displaying a calendar but the month is 1 digit out. EG June displays 5 instead of 6.

take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/jwoodcreative/vgTN7/

What am I doing wrong...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaScript months start from 0. Just add 1 to it. From the [MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth) (emphasis added):

> The value returned by `getMonth` is an integer **between 0 and 11**. 0
>   corresponds to January, 1 to February, and so on.

This is defined in the [ECMAScript specification](http://es5.github.com/#x15.9.1.4):

> Months are identified by an integer in the range 0 to 11, inclusive.

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vgTN7/1/).

Comment: Thanks, that’s solved it. Will accept answer in 10 mins (wont let medo it yet)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the docs https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

> **month**
>       Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for January to 11 for December.